# Ignore NaT while aggregating to create set in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,1,1], 
               'val1': ['2019-01-01 00:00:00', np.datetime64('NaT'), '2019-01-02 00:00:00'],
               'val2': [np.datetime64('NaT'), '2019-01-03 00:00:00', '2019-01-04 00:00:00']})

    ID  val1        val2
0   1   2019-01-01  NaT
1   1   NaT         2019-01-03
2   1   2019-01-02  2019-01-04
```

I am creating aggregates, convert `val` column to set. However I want to ignore the `NaT` value

Currently I am getting this

```
df.groupby('ID')[['val1', 'val2']].agg({'set': lambda x: set(x) })
ID  set
1   {NaT, 2019-01-02 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:00:00} {NaT, 2019-01-03 00:00:00, 2019-01-04 00:00:00}
```

how can I ignore `NaT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `np.nan != np.nan`, so also `np.NaT != np.NaT`. Then is possible filter in set comprehension:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['val1', 'val2']
         .agg({'set': lambda x: set([y for y in x if y == y])}))
print (df1)
  ID set                                              \
      ID                                        val1   
0  1   1  {2019-01-02 00:00:00, 2019-01-01 00:00:00}   


                                         val2  
0  {2019-01-04 00:00:00, 2019-01-03 00:00:00}
```

Another idea is add [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), but it should be slowier:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['val1', 'val2']
        .agg({'set': lambda x: set(x.dropna())}))
```

Comment: I did not understand, how `np.NaT != np.NaT`

Comment: I cannot use `dropna` because I have multiple columns, where one column maybe NaT, but the adjacent column can have value

Comment: @Hardikgupta - You can check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) - `Note that pandas/NumPy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan,` in red warning table